# Want to run three treads Odd Even and Sum

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to run three threads Odd (Printing Odd No), Even (Printing Even No) and SUM (Printing their SUM), Code is working fine but program is not terminated. Even thread is still waiting

package viv.tyagi.EvenOddThrad.EvenOddAndSumCorrectVersion;

```
public class EvenOddAndSum
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EvenOdd obj = new EvenOdd();

        Even e = new Even(obj);
        Odd o = new Odd(obj);
        Sum s = new Sum(obj);
        Thread oddThraed= new Thread(o,"Odd");
        Thread evenThraed= new Thread(e,"Even");
        Thread sumThraed= new Thread(s,"SUM");

        oddThraed.start();
        evenThraed.start();
        sumThraed.start();

    }



}



class EvenOdd 
{
     int seq;
     int evenNo;
     int oddNo=-1;
     int sum=0;  // 0 for odd , 1 for even , 2 for sum 

     public synchronized int getEvenNo()
     {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Before seq"+seq);

        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "waiting ...." + "seq is " + seq);
            if (seq == 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {

                try
                {
                    wait();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "released ...." + "seq is " + seq);
        }

         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"After seq"+seq);

         evenNo=evenNo+2;
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" even---------------------------------------->"+evenNo);
         seq=2;
         notifyAll();

         return evenNo;
     }

     public synchronized int getOddNo()
     {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Before seq"+seq);

         while (true)
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "waiting ...." + "seq is " + seq);
                if (seq == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    try
                    {
                        wait();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "released ...." + "seq is " + seq);
            }

         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"After seq"+seq);
         oddNo=oddNo+2;
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" odd---------------------------------------->"+oddNo);
         seq=1;
         notifyAll();

         return oddNo;
     }

     public synchronized int getSum()
     {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Before seq"+seq);

         while (true)
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "waiting ...." + "seq is " + seq);
                if (seq == 2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    try
                    {
                        wait();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "released ...." + "seq is " + seq);
            }

         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"After seq"+seq);
         sum=oddNo+evenNo;
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" sum---------------------------------------->"+sum);
         seq=0;
         notifyAll();

         return sum;
     }

}



class Even implements Runnable
{
    EvenOdd obj;

    Even(EvenOdd obj)
    {
        this.obj=obj;
    }



    public void run()
    {


        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        obj.getEvenNo();
            try{
        //  Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }   
    }
}

class Odd implements Runnable
{
    EvenOdd obj;

    Odd(EvenOdd obj)
    {
        this.obj=obj;
    }

    public void run()
    {

        for(int j=1;j<10;j++)
        {
            obj.getOddNo();
        }   
    }
}

class Sum implements Runnable
{
    EvenOdd obj;

    Sum(EvenOdd obj)
    {
        this.obj=obj;
    }

    public void run()
    {

        for(int k=1;k<10;k++)
        {
            obj.getSum();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Even` thread loops 10 times (i=0..9) while the others only 9 times (j/k=1..9). Therefore it waits (forever) for some other thread to tell him it is his turn (by setting `seq=1` and `notifyAll`) but this will never happen because the other threads have already terminated. You will want to fix the loop limits.

Comment: thanks, for me it was looking some thread notification problem but its a simple thing